# Get the Product Count on Category with only In-Stock Status

Tags: magento-1.9, product, category, ce-1.9.0.1

How to get the product count in a certain category with the product status of in-stock only?

Answer (score 2):

**Try this:**

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');

$cond = array(
    '{{table}}.use_config_manage_stock = 0 AND {{table}}.manage_stock=1 AND {{table}}.is_in_stock=1',
    '{{table}}.use_config_manage_stock = 0 AND {{table}}.manage_stock=0',
);


    $cond[] = '{{table}}.use_config_manage_stock = 1 AND {{table}}.is_in_stock=1';


$collection->joinField(
    'inventory_in_stock',
    'cataloginventory/stock_item',
    'is_in_stock',
    'product_id=entity_id',
    '(' . join(') OR (', $cond) . ')'
);


$category_model = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
$category = $category_model->load($category_id);
$collection->addCategoryFilter($category);
```

***For getting count try Count()/getSize();***

```
$count=$collection->count();
```

Comment: and where would be the number of products variable?

Comment: did got get by " the number of products variable?"

Comment: where can I get the Count of Products? That would be my question.

Comment: Why do you use literal conditions and not ->where() filters on the collection after the join?